# Keeping markup IDs unique for panel elements

Tags: wicket

I have a Panel that I'm using to display information about a location.  I have a page that I'm using to display information about a Delivery Appointment that involves two locations.  My Delivery page includes the Location Panel twice - once for the Origin and once for the Destination.  This example has been simplified so the Location only has a single property of Name.

### **Question:**

What is the best way to set the Markup ID for the Name (and other properties) of both locations while keeping them unique?

---

### Sample Code

**LocationPanel.java**

```
public class LocationPanel extends BasePanel {

    public LocationPanel(String id, String locCode) {
        super(id);
        init(locCode);
    }

    private void init(String locCode) {
        LocationInfo locModel = new LocationInfo(locCode + " Location");
        CompoundPropertyModel model = new CompoundPropertyModel(locModel);
        Label name = new Label("name");
        setDefaultModel(model);
        add(name);
    }
}
```

**LocationPanel.html**

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<body>
    <wicket:panel>
        <h3><span wicket:id="name">SAMPLE location</span></h3>
    </wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

**SetDeliveryAppointment.java**

```
public class SetDeliveryAppointment extends BaseWebPage{

    public SetDeliveryAppointment(String id) {
        super(id);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        Panel origin = new RampLocationInformationPanel("origin", "LAX");
        Panel dest = new RampLocationInformationPanel("dest", "DAL");
        WebMarkupContainer delivery = new WebMarkupContainer("delivery");
        delivery.add(origin);
        delivery.add(dest);
        add(delivery);
    }
}
```

**SetDeliveryAppointment.html**

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<body>
<wicket:extend>
    <wicket:container wicket:id="delivery">
        <div wicket:id="origin"></div>
        <div wicket:id="dest"></div>
    </wicket:container>
</wicket:extend>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### The Goal:

So what I'd like to see in the resulting HTML is as follows

**Final HTML View Source Goal**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="origin">
        <!-- The exact id doesn't matter -->
        <!-- as long as 'origin' and 'name' are contained in it -->
        <h3><span id="origin_name">LAX location</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div id="dest">
        <h3><span id="dest_name">DAL location</span></h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Bonus:**
This is really a cross-cutting concern.  We'd ideally like every Wicket component to get a unique ID, but we want it to be predictable based on the rules we prescribe.  The perfect solution would address this.

*Disclaimer: I'm new to Wicket, so go easy on me if this is a silly question*

Comment: What problem do you have with the code? Looks like correct for me. Each component is uniquely accessible by hierarchy. First `name` will have path `delivery:origin:name`, the second will be `delivery:dest:name`. Wicket produces unique html markup IDs automatically (for use it in javascript/etc).

Comment: @kan Because if I let Wicket take care of naming I get `<div id="namef"></div><div id="name11"></div>`.  I need a reliable way to be able to reference these for JS and possibly Selenium testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use JS, you should not use #id (e.g. as in jQuery use relative selectors) or generate a javascript snippet where you will pass `component.getMarkupId()`.

Not sure about selenium, probably better is to use the wicket test framework (it's quite powerful).

Comment: Maybe I'm not familiar with a relative selector in the sense that you mean.  Isn't the point of a unique DOM ID is that it allows you to pinpoint an object no matter where it is on a page?  Then if the page layout changes dramatically your CSS and JS won't break.  Not to mention the performance benefits of DOM `getElementById`.  http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: The problem here is the wicket approach. Each wicket component you make should be independent and self-contained. You could put them as much as you want without any clashes. E.g. now you have one `delivery` on a page. But tomorrow you need to build a list of them on the same page, it will be not trivial to change these `ID`s, it will be impossible to provide fixed strings for them. And wicket generates unique ID for each of them automatically.

Comment: I disagree and I think any changes that would need to be made to accommodate multiple deliveries would be small compared to the hacks needed to be put in place to handle the fragility of Wicket's auto generated DOM ids.

Comment: @Snekse From wicket point of view, just replace the `WebMarkupContainer` by `RepeatingView`, that's all (of course if you don't use any hacks such as you are asking for). And it's fragile at all.

Comment: So if I wanted each "name" to have a uniqueID, but I wanted it to be predictable - even if that is just "name1", "name2", etc, how would I do that when the Name Label is embedded in a Panel?  relying on Wicket's auto naming is not an option given the seemingly random naming.  To have 2 Panels on a page and have "name" IDs of "namef" and "name11" is unacceptable to me.

Comment: @Snekse I don't see any real reason to have it predictable, it works the same way as XSLT's `generate-id()` function, and it does its job well. If you really need it, read the source code and see how it's generated. But better solution is to use `getMarkupId()` to generate IDs into output somehow and then you don't need predict anything.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it's the only one that has any votes, though I still disagree with it.  I hope newer versions of Wicket make it easier.  Best of luck to current and future Wicket users.

Comment: @Snekse Huh... Old question. We are now using selenium (no wicket though), and usually we don't use getElementById as it is quite fragile. In Selenium is much better to select elements by its content, text, class and/or ancestry. So, Selenium navigates the page using natural navigation, as close as possible to what a human would do, while `id` is just a surrogate key.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `setMarkupId("origin");` and `setMarkupId("destination");` (I don't remember if a `setOutputMarkupId();` is mandatory to make it work though) on each instance of your panel. Keep it mind that you have to take care of uniqueness of ids in the page (but Wicket won't generate name colliding with 'origin' nor 'destination').

Edit : explain a little more how to do it, I would write `LocationPanel.java` this way :

```
public class LocationPanel extends BasePanel {

   public LocationPanel(String id, String locCode) {
    super(id);
    //sets the markupId to the wicket:id passed
    //you'll have to make sure you don't have the same wicket:id in the whole hierarchy
    //of your page though 
    setMarkupId(id);
    setOutputMarkupId(true);
    init(locCode);
   }

   private void init(String locCode) {
    LocationInfo locModel = new LocationInfo(locCode + " Location");
    CompoundPropertyModel model = new CompoundPropertyModel(locModel);
    Label name = new Label("name");
    setDefaultModel(model);
    add(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean.  Can you provide code examples?  I'll edit my question to make it clearer what I'm looking for.

Comment: I've edited my answer, if I have correctly understood what you want, I think it can do the trick.

Comment: Wouldn't there still be two elements with a DOM `id` of "name"?  It seems like you'd have to pass the id param from the constructor into the init(..) method so you could call setMarkupId and setOutputMarkupId on the label with a concat of the id param and the component's wicket id.  If that's the case, then you'd also have to do that for every other property would would really cause some code explosion.

Comment: No because the `id` passed to your `Panel` corresponds to the `wicket:id` in the parent container, in your case `origin` and `dest` respectively.

Comment: By reading another time your question, I found out I have missed out the origin_name thing, you can follow the similar pattern by concat as you say (or use a cssClass if your goal is to be able to select it `#origin .name`)

Answer (score 0):

So here is one way it can be accomplished.  If the Model on the Parent of the Component is an `instanceof` `CompoundPropertyModel`, then the Id of that parent component can be used to alter the Markup Id of the child.

```
public class ComponentMarkupListener implements IComponentOnBeforeRenderListener {
  public void onBeforeRender(Component component) {
    if (component instanceof WebMarkupContainer || component instanceof Label) {
        component.setOutputMarkupId(true);

        if((component.getParent().getDefaultModel()) instanceof CompoundPropertyModel ){
          component.setMarkupId(component.getParent().getId()
              +"_"+ component.getId() + "_ID");
        }else{
          component.setMarkupId(component.getId() + "_ID");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always a tradeoff between using an HTML `class` and using an HTML `id`. When developing a Wicket component, the component should have the ultimate goal of reusability should it not? My personal preference is to stick with `class`, especially if reusing components on the same page. Then you rely on their hierarchy (being as non-specific as possible) with JS integration, CSS styling and Selenium tests.

Comment: Understand.  Our UI architect had requested that we attach a DOM `id` to all of our Wicket components so they could be referenced easier.  We are trying to come up with a solution that will work, but when reusing components, it seems like the only surefire way to ensure uniqueness is to trace all the way up the inheritance tree to  include everything as part of the `id`.  And as @kan pointed out, if you use a repeating view, you're going to have the same parents.

Comment: I suspect that uniqueness for the purposes of JS integration is somewhat of a red herring, especially when dealing with event handlers on reusable components.